# Set Fragment on Tab with multi line title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I'm working with two fragments that I'm setting on the Tabs.

[image]

I have two issues:

1. I want to set the title of the fragment in multi line instead of "..."

here's the code to add fragment and set its title

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Current\nSubscription");
```

2. I want to remove the extra space from around the icon and text on the tab to make it more compact and save some space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this set Your `TabLayout` title using below code

```
TextView tabOne = new TextView(this);
tabOne.setText("Current"+ System.getProperty("line.separator") +"Subscription");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing "..." in tab titles will not make a good UI experience I suggest that you should set tabmode to scrollable and let tab titles take as much space they want.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
setting the height to actionBarSize removed all unwanted spaces. Thanks

Comment: it is height of action-bar if you did not getting then you can also define manually like                           <item name="actionBarSize">56.0dip</item>

Comment: otherwise you replace  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" this with  android:layout_height="56.0dip"